# Conformal map sending real axis to itself with 4 specified points sent to 4 points symmetric about the imaginary axis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$ be real numbers. Let $\lambda$ be a positive real number larger than 1. How do we construct a conformal mapping on the extended complex plane that sends $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ to $-\lambda, -1, 1, \lambda$ respectively?

Comment: Do you mean a Möbius transformation?

Comment: I think a possible answer could be a Möbius transform but not sure if a Möbius transform is the only possible answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the conformal mapping to be defined on the Riemann sphere (I suppose this is what you mean by the extended complex plane?) then it has to be a Möbius transformation. Then note that any Möbius transformation has to preserve crossratios, i.e. writing:

$$ R(x_1,x_2;x_3,x_4) = \frac{(x_1-x_3)(x_2-x_4)}{(x_1-x_4)(x_2-x_3)} $$
then we have the auxiliary condition on $\lambda$ (up to permutations on the $x_i$'s):
$$ R(x_1,x_2;x_3,x_4) = R(\lambda,1; -1,-\lambda) $$
In order to construct $M(z)=(az+b)/(cz+d)$ the easiest is perhaps to map $x_1,x_2,x_3$ first to $0,1,\infty$ and then to $\lambda,1,-1$, say. Find the value of  $\lambda$ that verifies the auxiliary condition (then automatically $x_4$ will be mapped to -$\lambda$). For the first map you may take:
$$ M(z) = \frac{(z-x_1)(x_2-x_3)}{(z-x_3)(x_2-x_1)}$$
For the second it should be:
$$ N(z) = \frac{(\lambda-1)z+\lambda}{(1-\lambda)z-2} $$
then compose the two (but it will look quite horrible)

Comment: Thank you very much! I originally interpreted my own question to mean that $\lambda$ was to be fixed beforehand - and that I have realized is erroneous; indeed your solution is the correct interpretation, namely, that $\lambda$ is determined uniquely by $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. The solution you provided is very clear. My appreciation!

Comment: You are welcome!